# Automatically Update Order Status to Complete When Shipment Tracking Number Input - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to automatically update the order status in WooCommerce when the tracking information is inputted via the official WooCommerce Shipment Tracking plugin. I found the doc from Woo on how to automatically complete orders, but I only want this to execute when the tracking number is added. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the code from Woo:

```
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

And here are the meta references from the plugin:

The Shipping Tracking plugin stores the tracking information in the order meta with the meta key _wc_shipment_tracking_items. It’s an array with the following structure:

- tracking_provider — String of predefined provider
- custom_tracking_provider — String of custom provider
- custom_tracking_link — String of custom tracking URL tracking_number
- String of tracking number date_shipped — Timestamp of shipment date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you are using the "WooCommerce Shipment Tracking plugin." but in that plugin, I didn't find any filters or hooks that will help to update status when the tracking number is added. but I found that they use `update_post_meta()` to update the tracking code so you can use the `update_postmeta` action hook to update order status.

Try the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ){
    if( $meta_key == '_wc_shipment_tracking_items' ){
        error_log('update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input');
        $order = wc_get_order( $object_id );
        if( $order ){
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'update_postmeta', 'update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Hey @Bhautik - I added a custom carrier option, but I'm finding out that the order is not being updated to "completed" when I use this custom option. Any pointers? I used the WooCommerce guide - not sure if I need to reference this new data?

https://woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/#h-add-custom-providers-dynamically